# Get longer stack trace on node process out of memory error?

Tags: node.js, out-of-memory

Is there a way to get a longer stacktrace when node runs into an out of memory error?

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   39984 ms: Scavenge 594.7 (636.8) -> 594.7 (637.8) MB, 0.5 / 0 ms (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
   40058 ms: Mark-sweep 594.7 (637.8) -> 382.8 (411.8) MB, 73.7 / 0 ms (+ 32.0 ms in 5 steps since start of marking, biggest step 32.0 ms) [last resort gc].
   40096 ms: Mark-sweep 382.8 (411.8) -> 382.5 (409.8) MB, 38.0 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 07985C51 <JS Object>
    1: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:158] [pc=2CE5D269] (this=079080C9 <undefined>,p=351F00A9 <JS Array[34]>,v=34,C=249FA8A5 <String[1]: ,>,B=07976BD1 <JS Function ConvertToString (SharedFunctionInfo 07945515)>)
    2: InnerArrayJoin(aka InnerArrayJoin) [native array.js:335] [pc=2CE5C475] (this=079080C9 <undefined>,C=249FA8A5 <String[1]: ,>,p=351F00A9 <JS Array[34]>,v=34)
    3: join [native array....

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Only three lines of the stack trace are shown. Is there a way to get more information on what was happening right before the error?

I've tried these node flags which didn't seem to help in this situation.

```
--trace_track_allocation_sites 
--stack_trace_limit=40 
--builtins_in_stack_traces 
--stack_trace_on_illegal
```

In my case after a database error is received and handled (bad sql, not what I'm concerned with), about 30 seconds later I get an out of memory error. As far as I can tell my application isn't doing anything in these 30 seconds. There are no additional calls from client to server (every call is written to console) and when I run it through the debugger, after the last step over, 30 seconds pass without the debugger breaking on any line (either if I wait or if I click pause).

The above is from Node 5.5.0. The error happens in 0.12.9 but that version doesn't produce any stack trace. Node 4.2.6 give the same three-level stack trace.

Comment: did you solve your problem? I've catched the same...

Comment: @Alerkesi, No, I did not solve the problem and put it on back burner for now, which means continuing to use an older version of the library until I can figure out what's triggering it (not faulting library, just something we're doing that is interacting with the library in an unexpected way).

Comment: I've found some issue in my case, maybe this help you:
I've set before:
$ npm set config tmp Disc:\myFolder
but space on Disc is 1Gb, and as JS notifies me: it is not enough.
I rollback config 'tmp' to default folder 'AppData\Local\Temp'.
I don't know how JS use this folder for GarbageCollector or someone else, I thought JS save this in Memory. no minds...but now it is ok for me. I've installed node and npm on one hard disc, but launch 'npm install' on another disc (1Gb, i've created that from RAM via plugin DataRam - performance is amazing :-))

Comment: @Alerkesi thanks, and totally agree about DataRam, it is amazing.